# Mongo pull shell command in a complex structure

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection structured as following :

```
    > db.mycollection.find().pretty()

 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55df1066372f262a3cd85742"),
    "object" : "object_1",
    "startTime" : {
            "arg1" : "value",
            "arg2" : "value"
    },
    "stopTime" : {
            "arg1" : "value",
            "arg2" : "value"
    },
    "aTime" : NumberLong(3600000),
    "otherAttribute1" : 316.87,
    "otherAttribute2" : "_453",
    "highObject" : {
            "priority" : "HIGH_PRIORITY",
            "spaceUsedPercent" : 0,
            "finalUsedSpace" : 0,
            "initialUsedSpace" : 0,
            "myObjectsToPull" : [
                    {
                            "attribute1" : "value1",
                            "embeddedList" : [
                                    {
                                            "embeddedId" : "331",
                                            "otherAttribute1" : 20
                                    }
                            ],
                            "status" : "INVALID",
                            "_id" : NumberLong(10)
                    }
            ]
    },
    "lowObject" : {
            "priority" : "LOW_PRIORITY",
            "spaceUsedPercent" : 0,
            "finalUsedSpace" : 0,
            "initialUsedSpace" : 0,
            "myObjectsToPull" : [ ]
    }
}, 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("73defr66372f262a3cd85742"),
 […]
```

I would like to remove some elements from the myObjectsToPull list using $pull command.

If there are others commands doing the removal I am also interested.

I tried the pull mongo command but the result remains the same :

```
> db.mycollection.update({},{$pull:{myObjectsToPull:{"_id" : 10}}, false, true) 

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field is embedded in other field named `highObject`, so your query is not pointing to correct field: Check the following, it should work:

```
db.mycollection.update({},{$pull:{"highObject.myObjectsToPull":{"_id" : 10}, "lowObjectObject.myObjectsToPull":{"_id" : 10}}, false, true)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But the field list is not only embedded in highObject, this list is also embedded in lowObject. And I would like to pull out all the objectsToPull which have a given "_id" (from highObject or lowObject).

Comment: then you should append that field to $pull too, I updated my answer you can check it.